# How to query SQLite data between start of month and today

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have  a table contain column_date in which the date saved as String yyyy-mm-dd
i query the last week by the code

```
    String query = "select * from table_name where e_date  >= date('now','-7 days') order by e_date DESC";
```

and it works fine but if i used

```
    String query = "select * from expenses where e_date  >= date('now','-30 days') order by e_date DESC";
```

it gives me the last 30 day but what i need is the current month from first day of month till now .
any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: just pass in an integer of the current day of the month as a minus value

Answer (score 3):

There are `start of month` and `localtime` [modifers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for the SQLite `date()` function, so you could simply do

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE e_date BETWEEN date('now','localtime','start of month') AND date('now','localtime') "
```

---

If you want to do it in Java, you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get a `yyyy-MM-dd` String for both today and the start of the month.

Then assuming `e_date` is type `TEXT`, you can query with string concatenation

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE " + monthStart + " <= e_date AND e_date <= " + today;
```

Or, using `BETWEEN`

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE e_date BETWEEN " + monthStart + " AND " + today;
```

For example

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
String monthStart = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

c = Calendar.getInstance(); // reset
String today = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

System.out.println(monthStart + " to " + today);
```

Running this on March 16, 2016 will print

```
2016-03-01 to 2016-03-16
```

Comment: do you want to say String today = "2016-03-16";     and String monthstart = "2016-03-01";

Comment: Why? If I run that code tomorrow, then I don't want `"2016-03-16"`, but `"2016-03-17"`

Comment: so  how to get String today and monthstart, can you tell me ?

Comment: sorry i just seen it

Comment: the code doesn't work when i put it in my app what problem do you think

Comment: In your SQLite CREATE statement, what type of column did you make as `e_date`?

Comment: Alright, then it should work. If you are getting no results, then either your database does not have data in yyyy-MM-dd format or there are no values in the specified range.

Comment: thank you cricket-007  this code is working good                                   String query = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE e_date between date('now','localtime','start of month') and date('now','localtime') " ;

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it before with my android application, try this

```
final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
startCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM expenses  WHERE   date( e_date/1000,'unixepoch','localtime')   >= '" + (SDF.format(startCal.getTime())) + "'  And  date( e_date/1000,'unixepoch','localtime')   <= '" + (SDF.format(endCal.getTime())) + "'";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: Not sure why you needed to convert to epoch time

Comment: As time stored as long in the database to get it as yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format you have to convert it.

Comment: Ah, if the column type is TEXT, you can do direct comparisons